# C# covariance on abstractly implemented interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, covariance, derived-class

Using C#/.NET 4.0 I was hoping the following scenario would be possible:

```
interface IA<out TB> where TB : IB { }
interface IB { }

class A<TB> : IA<TB> where TB : IB { }
class B : IB { }


abstract class AbstractA<TB> : IA<TB> where TB : IB { }
class DerivedA<TB> : AbstractA<TB> where TB : IB { }

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var myAB = new A<B>();
    Debug.Assert(myAB is IA<B>); // fine
    Debug.Assert(myAB is IA<IB>); // fine

    var myDerivedAB = new DerivedA<B>();
    Debug.Assert(myDerivedAB is IA<IB>); // fine
    Debug.Assert(myDerivedAB is DerivedA<B>); // fine
    Debug.Assert(myDerivedAB is DerivedA<IB>); // NOT fine        
}
```

Sadly the last test fails, although the types clearly are compatible. Would there be another way to test this, other than testing for every known implementation of IB?

```
class FirstB : IB { }
class SecondB : IB { }
Debug.Assert(myDerivedAB is DerivedA<FirstB> || myDerivedAB is DerivedA<SecondB>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GetGenericArguments method of Type object:

```
Type t = myDerivedAB.GetType();
if (t.IsGenericType)
{
    Type[] typeArguments = t.GetGenericArguments();
    Debug.Assert(typeArguments.Length > 0 && typeArguments[0] is IB);
}
```

By this you can get the Generic parameter of the `myDerivedAB` object, and check its type, or something else you need.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Is it then also possible to cast an IA<IB> for which we know it's a DerivedA<B> to a DerivedA<IB>?

Comment: @Frank Razenberg You can implement the [cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) for this, if you need.

Comment: Thanks. So I should define an explicit conversion operator on every implementation of IB then? I'm a bit confused, if it's not too much to ask, would you be able to give an example?

Comment: @Frank Razenberg Well, you can define a cast operator for the interfaces, but I still suggest to use generic parameters from `Type` definition. Its much more simpler.

Comment: Is the cast operator really necessary? When casting, the code /does/ compile, but the cast is invalid.

Comment: @Frank Razenberg Only if you want to cast one object to another. And it fails, I'm sure, because you didn't implement it.

Answer (score 5):

> although the types clearly are compatible

No they aren't; C# covariance via `out` applies only to interfaces and delegates (of reference-types, although that is fine here). It does not apply to classes such as `Derived<T>`.